# how to hide errors in status bar for unsaved (dirty) files in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

As shown in the screenshot, status bar shows errors from unsaved (dirty) files. How to tell VSCode not to show errors from unsaved files?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there's no built in way to do this. I suppose you could write an extension that provides an alternate count like you want using [`languages.getDiagnostics()`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#languages) and then creates a status bar indicator filtering out diagnostics for the active document, but <s>I'd suggest that you first try [raising a feature-request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=feature_request.md) and see how that goes.</s> An issue ticket was raised at [Hide errors in status bar from unsaved (dirty) files #202799](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/202799) and it seems that the VS Code maintainers consider this out of scope, and would rather have it be implemented as a configuration point on a per-extension-basis ([source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/202799#issuecomment-1904357905)).

Comment: thanks I created a feature request https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/202799